# Imagemagick antialias text

Tags: imagemagick, antialiasing

photoshop has strong anti-alias text effect.

Although imagemagick has anti-alias option. but, does not have anti-alias type like photoshop.

is there any way to get similar strong anti-alias text effect with imagemagick ?

Comment: To *which* one of the many photoshop text anti-alias-types are you referring to? What have you done so far?

Comment: i am refering antialias setting described in this page http://tutorialblog.org/photoshop-which-anti-alias-setting-is-best/

Comment: There are multiple in your example. For example the first variant should be supported out of the box with imagemagick, but I assume that's not the one you're looking for (the none variant), so for which ones are you looking?

Comment: i am looking for strong antialias effect

Answer (score 0):

It's not a perfect solution (I'm just learning this myself) but it will get you close: You can print the text larger and add a stroke at whatever size you choose then shrink it down after. Example code:

```
$template_file= "blank.png"; // a transparent png
$template_blob = file_get_contents($template_file);
$width = 100;
$height = 50;
$mult = 6;
$template = new imagick();
$template->readImageBlob($template_blob);
$template->setImageDepth(8);
$template->setCompressionQuality(100); 
$template->setCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_NO);
$template->setImageFormat("png");


$points = array( 
   $mult, //scale by which you enlarge it
   0 //# rotate
);

$template->distortImage( imagick::DISTORTION_SCALEROTATETRANSLATE, $points, TRUE ); 

$color = '#000000';

$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$pixel = new ImagickPixel('none');
$draw->setFont('Arial.ttf');
$draw->setFontSize($font_size*$mult);
$draw->setFillColor($color);
$draw->setStrokeColor($color);
$draw->setStrokeWidth(1);
$draw->setStrokeAntialias(true);
$draw->setTextAntialias(true);
$draw->settextkerning($mult); // adjust the kerning if you like

$template->annotateImage($draw, $x_indent, $y_indent, $some_angle, $text);

$points = array( 
   1/$mult, // set it back to the original scale
    0 // rotate
);

$template->distortImage( imagick::DISTORTION_SCALEROTATETRANSLATE, $points, TRUE ); 

 //Do something with the $template here like:
 $template->writeImage("test.png");

$template->clear();
$template->destroy();
$draw->clear();
$draw->destroy();
```